# How can be changed the linux system's default character set?

Tags: linux, configuration, encoding, charset

I'm working in a software development team using svn. Since many developer's computers are working using windows, text file codification has to be agreed with everyone. I decided to use Linux, and probably I will have to change my machine's default character codification. How can this be done in Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is ensuring  that the LC_ALL and LANG variables are set to something like en@UTF-8 or cn_ZH@UTF-16 or whatever. The format is countrycode_LANGUAGE@CHARSET.

How you set this globally depends on your distribution. Try /etc/sysconfig/i18n. It never hurts adding

```
export LC_ALL=<whatever>
export LANG=<whatever>
```

to your users ~/.bashrc though.

Also, read `man 1 locale`.